# Why Liquid crystal display doesn't give output in code below?

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-ide, display

I've been working on project for children showing the codes used by atc transponder. I've used a keypad and a 16×2 display , where user types a 4 digit code and display shows condition related to the code
E.g. typing 7500 on keypad will show hijack on display

What has went wrong??

```
My code is ------
    #include <LiquidCrystal.h>
// initialize the library with the numbers of the interface pins
LiquidCrystal lcd(8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13);//RS,EN,D4,D5,D6,D7
#include <Keypad.h>//header for keypad commands enabling
const byte ROWS = 4; // Four rows
const byte COLS = 4; // Three columns
// Define the Keymap
char keys[ROWS][COLS] = {
  {'1','2','3','A'},
  {'4','5','6','B'},
  {'7','8','9','C'},
  {'#','0','*','D'}
};
// Connect keypad ROW0, ROW1, ROW2 and ROW3 to these Arduino pins.
byte rowPins[ROWS] = { 0, 1, 2, 3 };
// Connect keypad COL0, COL1 and COL2 to these Arduino pins.
byte colPins[COLS] = { 4, 5, 6, 7 };
//  Create the Keypad
Keypad kpd = Keypad( makeKeymap(keys), rowPins, colPins, ROWS, COLS );

char inputArray[4]; //array to gather user keypad presses
char Vfr[4] = {'1','2','0','0'}; //array to hold keypad password
char Gliders[4] = {'1','2','0','2'};
char Hijack[4] = {'7','5','0','0'};
char Comfail[4] = {'7','6','0','0'};
char Emerg[4] = {'7','7','0','0'};
char Mic[4] = {'7','7','7','7'};

int i = 0;
int state = 1;

void setup()
{
  for(int k=8;k<14;k++)
  {
    pinMode(k,OUTPUT);//pins 8-14 are enabled as output
  }
  lcd.begin(16, 2);//initializing LCD
}

void loop()
{
while (state = 1);
{
 lcd.setCursor(0, 0);

 char key = kpd.getKey();

 //if a key is presseds
   if(key)
     {

     inputArray[i] = key; //store entry into array
     i++;
     lcd.clear(); //print keypad character entry to serial port

     if (key=='C');
       {
         lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
         lcd.print("Reset");
         i=0; //reset i
       }

     if (i == 4) //if 4 presses have been made
       {
         {

         //match input array to password array

           if (inputArray[0] == Vfr[0] &&
           inputArray[1] == Vfr[1] &&
           inputArray[2] == Vfr[2] &&
           inputArray[3] == Vfr[3])
              {
               lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
               lcd.print("VFR");
              }
         }

         {

         //match input array to password array

           if (inputArray[0] == Gliders[0] &&
           inputArray[1] == Gliders[1] &&
           inputArray[2] == Gliders[2] &&
           inputArray[3] == Gliders[3])
              {
               lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
               lcd.print("GLIDERS");
              }
         }

         {

         //match input array to password array

           if (inputArray[0] == Hijack[0] &&
           inputArray[1] == Hijack[1] &&
           inputArray[2] == Hijack[2] &&
           inputArray[3] == Hijack[3])
              {
               lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
               lcd.print("HIJACK");
              }
         }

         {

         //match input array to password array

           if (inputArray[0] == Comfail[0] &&
           inputArray[1] == Comfail[1] &&
           inputArray[2] == Comfail[2] &&
           inputArray[3] == Comfail[3])
              {
               lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
               lcd.print("COMMFAIL");
              }
         }

         {

         //match input array to password array

           if (inputArray[0] == Emerg[0] &&
           inputArray[1] == Emerg[1] &&
           inputArray[2] == Emerg[2] &&
           inputArray[3] == Emerg[3])
              {
               lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
               lcd.print("EMERGENCY!");
              }
         }

         {

         //match input array to password array

           if (inputArray[0] == Emerg[0] &&
           inputArray[1] == Emerg[1] &&
           inputArray[2] == Emerg[2] &&
           inputArray[3] == Emerg[3])
              {
               lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
               lcd.print("EMERGENCY!");
              }
         }

         {

         //match input array to password array

           if (inputArray[0] == Mic[0] &&
           inputArray[1] == Mic[1] &&
           inputArray[2] == Mic[2] &&
           inputArray[3] == Mic[3])
              {
               lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
               lcd.print("MILITARY IC");
              }
         }
       }   
}
lcd.print(key); 
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while (state = 1);
```

This line is a loop that will go around forever so long as you can set the variable state to 1.  What you mean is:

```
while (state == 1)
```

You don't need semicolons at the end of conditionals, here is another:

```
 if (key=='C');
```

If you fix those two bugs, you'll get a lot further.

Comment: Thank you I tried  and now display seems to give some output but it's some weird character

Comment: The keys I'm typing on keypad are appearing on same cursor position ?????

Comment: You aren't incrementing the cursor position manually so have you initialised the LCD so it increments the cursor position?

Comment: How can I do it?

Comment: You'll need to read the command from the manual for your display, you haven't stated the make and model, so  can't help.  They are usually very easy to find.  Or `lcd.setCursor(0,x++);`

Comment: should I define x as int? From 0 to 16 right??

Comment: I tried-- for (int x=0; x<17;x++) lcd.setCursor(0,x++); and it did the same except changed my cursor position to (0,1) and still numbers are being typed on same position

Comment: I guess it has to do something with my array?